# Is there a way to retrieve a column from a foreign key table in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have 2 tables, country and state:

```
Country:
| ID | Name |

State:
| ID | Name | CountryID |
```

In the data model I would like to pull back the Country name with the ID. This is essentially a simple inner join on the Country table.

I know I can create a Country class and use it as a property in the State class:

```
    [Table("State")]
    public class StateEntity
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("CountryID")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        public string CountryName => Country?.Name;

        [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
        public virtual CountryEntity Country { get; set; }
    }
```

But this is very cumbersome and as this pattern is used a lot in my API is not a viable option. Is there a more generic way I could pull a column from another table in a join?

Comment: Does not fully understand what is wrong with adding `Country` to state entity?

Comment: @GuruStron Its a pain when there are more fks on the entity. For each fk one would have to add the property then go and include it where its being used. Thats fine for backend logic but when its just a rest api that just needs the name returned... there should be a better way

Comment: When using an ORM, you need to think in terms of objects/properties, not tables/columns. When you have a `State` object in hand, you navigate to a `Country` property to get the country's `Name`. That's how relations work in object oriented context. Or, you might forget the `Country` entity/table altogether, and simply add a `CountryName` property in your `State` model, if that suits you.

Comment: @user3854966 you can enable [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) so you will not need to manually use the `Include`, though it can have performance drawbacks. Personally I prefer to return specific DTO's from queries selecting all needed fields, this will not need explicit `Include` also and will allow to fetch only needed stuff. Also it can be "imporved" with automapper (which personally I prefer not to use, but it can be very handy in some cases).